# How to view blob data directly using html

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

How do you view a blob data that is from a sql database file (.db .db3 and others) and view it on web browser by only using a single html file? The blob data are probably meant to be seen as an image file (jpg, png and others)

Let's say I have a blob data like this:

du�� C�BVwv�q8q7k�1�H�asfdasdfasdf�#s;47sk"as��'7hib-�3$asdffdsfa�a�����U�����P������

And I want to put that single blob data directly (without calling the database file, just using the value of the blob itself) inside a html file so I can directly open it from my browser without installing other software or setting up a local server inside my computer.

I'm sorry if I explain this weirdly, I rarely code, I honestly don't know anything about sql or that server thingamajig, I just want to view the blob file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). Here I construct a blob and then turn it back into a string that I insert in the `document.body`.

```js
var array = ['<p>Hello World!</p>'];
var blob = new Blob(array, {type : 'text/html'});

const reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener('loadend', e => {
   document.body.innerHTML += e.target.result;
});

reader.readAsText(blob);
```

And I guess that the [Filereader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) can also read a file if needed.